# Need help building a Calendar UI for Android 2.2. Any suggestions on how to start?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, calendar, interactive

I am building a Calendar Application for Android OS. I have previously made some Android applications with built-in android widgets such as buttons and spinners etc. Now I want to create an Android Application that displays 4 'tabbed' views of a Calendar (month, week, day & list). I have already built the backend stuff for the application, I just need to display the events in an interactive UI. I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Any suggestions on how to go about doing this? Should I have a xml file with gridview that can update in real-time according to user interactions + current time. If so then do you have any open-source example of this?
2. Are there any open source calendar applications I can check for Calendar UI information?
3. I have to update the Calendar UI according to the current day and time. How can I do this?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be of interest to take a look at the [Android Calendar source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/calendar;h=627dcb4cc140ee338a5a84e4f739453761c9dc8d;hb=HEAD).